# Din - with or without an article

Tags: articles

I want to ask about an article.

**"Cars are going back and forward with (a?) din (noise)"**

Should "din" have an article? I don't concretize it and perceive the word as a concept, that is I don't pay attention to the features of that din, but it is produced by cars.

Thank you!

Comment: Using a/the with "din" is fine, but the entire sentence feels awkward and wrong to me, even though it seems perfectly grammatical.

Comment: One *makes* a din.  “Cars are going back and forth making quite a din’

Answer (score -1):

Please see http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/din

This entry has examples with "a din" and "the din."